# symfony twig include form_widget template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm using the following code to include a template for the data-prototype:

```
<ul class="factuurDetails list-unstyled"
    data-prototype="{% filter escape %}{% include 'FactuurBundle:Default:prototypeCreditnotaDetail.html.twig' with {'form': form.creditnotaDetails.vars.prototype} %}{% endfilter %}">
  {% for detail in form.creditnotaDetails %}
    <li>
       {{form_widget(detail) }}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But how do I apply this same template `prototypeCreditnotaDetail.html.twig` to the `{{form_widget(detail)}}` ?

Comment: Just include it with form as detail like `{% include 'FactuurBundle:Default:prototypeCreditnotaDetail.html.twig' with {'form': detail } %}`.

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't know that was possible. (You do have a small typo in your code ;-) )

Comment: Was it the `{{` when it should have been `{%`?

Comment: I usually use include as a function rather than a tag like `{{ include('template.hml.twig', {'form': detail }) }}` so I started with the function but then just copied and pasted the rest of your code instead. My bad. (I changed it anyway so it's like it never happened.. spooky).